# return the imported data from the opened file PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to return the opened data from the excel to use it in other functions
but I can't do such a thing!!
I used the return at the end of the fuction as I have mentioned in the comment in the code.
I used the global and still couldn't!!

when i use the global or return I have to call the open_file function which will pop up an open file
window!!

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog

a= Tk()
a.title('AAAAAAAA')
a.state('zoomed')

# def open_the_file ():
#     open_file = pd.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title ="Choose the Excel File", 
#     filetype=(("Excel Sheet",".xlsx"),("Excel Sheet",".xlsm"),("Excel Sheet",".xls") )))
#create menu bar

my_menu = Menu(gsp)

file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label= "File ", menu=file_menu)

file_menu.add_command(label= "New")
file_menu.add_command(label= "Open", command=lambda: open_the_file())
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label= "Save")
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label= 'Exit', command=gsp.quit)

method_choice = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label= "Method", menu=method_choice)

def r_m():
    import main2 
def g_m():
    import main4
def gg_m():
    import main5
def s_m():
    import main3

method_choice.add_command(label= "R M", command= r_m)
method_choice.add_separator()
method_choice.add_command(label= "GP M", command= g_m)
method_choice.add_separator()
method_choice.add_command(label= "G M", command= gg_m)
method_choice.add_separator()
method_choice.add_command(label= "S M", command= s_m)

about_info = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label= "Help", menu=about_info)

def about_soft():
    pass
def about_devo():
    from about import devo
about_info.add_command(label= "About Software", command= about_soft)
about_info.add_separator()
about_info.add_command(label= "About Devoloper", command= about_devo)
gsp.config(menu=my_menu)

def open_the_file():
    open_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Open Excel File',initialdir='/',
        filetype=(("Excel Sheet",".xlsx"),("Excel Sheet",".xlsm"),("Excel Sheet",".xls") ))
    global xlsx
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(open_file)
    read_excelr()
    
def read_excelr():
    df=pd.read_excel(xlsx, index_col=0)
    print(df.values)
    # Here is the data I want to get it out to use in other places even in ather modules.
    # If i used the return I will need to call the open file to get the xlsx which will pop up an 
    # open file window with no permision!! So any ideas?



gsp.mainloop()
```

```
def read_excelr():
    df=pd.read_excel(xlsx, index_col=0)
    print(df.values)
    # Here is the data I want to get it out to use in other places even in ather modules.
    # If i used the return I will need to call the open file to get the xlsx which will pop up an 
    # open file window with no permision!! So any ideas?
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but why can't `read_excelr()` just `return df`? You can then call `read_excelr()`, and set its return equal to some variable and use that variable elsewhere, no?

Comment: I've removed the "Cython" tag because there's no indication you're using it

Comment: It's unclear. Also you need to post a [mre]. Anyway, do you want something like ```def read_excel(path): return pd.read_excel(path, index_col=0).values```?

Comment: Thank you for your response 'I do appreciate it'
one moment i'll answer

Comment: at this area:
'
def read_excelr():
    df=pd.read_excel(xlsx, index_col=0)
    print(df.values)
'
if i used the return instead of print it will need to call the open_the_file() function before it can be return!! so it will automatically ask for open window which i do not want to appear only if i click on open in the menu bar.

Comment: ``` 
def read_excel(path): return pd.read_excel(path, index_col=0).values
```
okay now i want to print the out put so i need to 
```
print(read_excel(path))
```
I'll need to call the path which mean pop up a choose file window which i need to pop up only when i click on the open in menubar, can i talk to you in discord or face or whats please?

Comment: See [ask]. You should CLEARLY describe your goal, logic, scenario, etc. To open a dialog or not, to print or not, etc. You can code whatever you want. Anyway, if you want to store the data frame of the Excel file selected by a user, use a global variable. To assign to a global variable inside a function, you should declare like ```global df```.